# How to extend the line under text form field till under visibility icon?

Tags: flutter, passwords, text-formatting

I have a text form field to enter password, I have added a visibility icon button with the field in a row. How do I extend the underline till under the icon?
(There is a validator in the text form field, so I want the exact same line extended so that the behavior is same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `IconButton` as a `prefixIcon` within the `TextFormField`:

```
child: TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.visibility),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ),
  ...
),
```